# How to make a range of dates avaible in DatePicker mvc4

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

I have a method that generate a range of dates. I want to make that range of dates avaible in the DatePicker and the rest of the dates has to be disabled.

This is the Jquery:

```
;(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $("form.xforms-form").bind({
            XForms_Enrich: function(e) {
                if ($.fn.datepicker) {
                    $("input.qmatic-dateslot", e.args.data).each(function() {


                        var inp = $(this);
                        if (inp.is(":disabled")) return;
                        var tabindex = inp.attr("tabindex");

                        var dateFormat = $.xforms.getProperty(inp, 'dateFormat') || 'd-M-yy';
                        dateFormat = dateFormat.replace(/m/g, '0').replace(/h/gi, '0').replace(/t/g, '').replace(/M/g, 'm').replace('yyyy', 'yy');

                        $("#" + inp.attr("id") + " ~ button.ui-datepicker-trigger").attr("tabindex", tabindex);

                        var clearBtn = $('<button class="ui-datepicker-clear" type="button" tabindex="' + tabindex + '">x</button>').click(function() {
                            inp.val('');
                            inp.change();
                            return false;
                        });
                        inp.after(clearBtn);



                        inp.datepicker({
                            dateFormat: dateFormat,
                            changeMonth: true,

                            beforeShowDay: function(date) {

                                var array = $.getJSON("/QMatic/GetAvailableDates"); //["2015-03-14", "2015-03-15", "2015-03-16"];
                                var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                                return [array.indexOf(string) == -1];
                            },
                            changeYear: false,
                            showWeek: true,
                            firstDay: 1,
                            yearRange: "c-100:c+15",
                            showOn: inp.hasClass("ui-date-picker-onfocus") ? "focus" : "button"

                        })

                    });

                    $("#ui-datepicker-div").hide();
                }
            }
        })
    })
})(jQuery);
```

and this is the method that generates the availeble in the class: QMatic:

```
public AvailableDates GetAvailableDates(string branchPublicId, string servicePublicId)
        {
            HttpWebRequest httpRequest = CreateHttpRequest("calendar-backend/public/api/v1/branches/" + branchPublicId + "/services/" + servicePublicId + "/dates", HttpMethod.Get, "application/json");
            string json = Get(httpRequest);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AvailableDates>(json);
        }
```

So it has to be client side. Because the dates are already available. But how to enable the range in the datepicker and disable the other dates?

Thank you

I try it like this:

```
 inp.datepicker({
                            dateFormat: dateFormat,
                            changeMonth: true,
                            url: "/QMatic/GetAvailableDates",
                            type: "GET",

                            beforeShowDay: function (date) {


                                var array = url; //$.getJSON("/QMatic/GetAvailableDates");  //["2015-03-14", "2015-03-15", "2015-03-16"];
                                var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                                return [array.indexOf(string) == -1];
                            },
                            changeYear: false,
                            showWeek: true,
                            firstDay: 1,
                            yearRange: "c-100:c+15",
                            showOn: inp.hasClass("ui-date-picker-onfocus") ? "focus" : "button"

                        })
```

but then even the DatePicker doenst work anymore

So this is hardcoded:

```
 var array = ["2015-03-14", "2015-03-15", "2015-03-16"];
```

But how to extract the dates from this method:

```
public AvailableDates GetAvailableDates(string branchPublicId, string servicePublicId)
        {
            HttpWebRequest httpRequest = CreateHttpRequest("calendar-backend/public/api/v1/branches/" + branchPublicId + "/services/" + servicePublicId + "/dates", HttpMethod.Get, "application/json");
            string json = Get(httpRequest);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AvailableDates>(json);
        }
```

Thank you!

This is the output of the json:

```
{"notifications":[],"dates":["2015-07-22T00:00:00","2015-07-23T00:00:00","2015-07-24T00:00:00","2015-07-27T00:00:00","2015-07-28T00:00:00","2015-07-29T00:00:00","2015-07-30T00:00:00","2015-07-31T00:00:00","2015-08-03T00:00:00","2015-08-04T00:00:00","2015-08-05T00:00:00","2015-08-06T00:00:00","2015-08-07T00:00:00","2015-08-10T00:00:00","2015-08-11T00:00:00","2015-08-12T00:00:00","2015-08-13T00:00:00","2015-08-14T00:00:00","2015-08-17T00:00:00","2015-08-18T00:00:00","2015-08-19T00:00:00"],"meta":{"start":"","end":"","totalResults":21,"offset":null,"limit":null,"fields":"","arguments":{}}}
```

I try it like this:

```
 inp.datepicker({
                            dateFormat: dateFormat,
                            changeMonth: true,
                            //url: "/QMatic/GetAvailableDates/",
                            type: "GET",                           
                            dataType: "application/json",
                            url: "~/GetAvailableDates, QMatic",
                            data:"{}",

                            beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                                var result = msg.d;

                                var array = []; //$.getJSON("/QMatic/GetAvailableDates");  //["2015-03-14", "2015-03-15", "2015-03-16"];
                                var len = result.length;
                                for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                                    array.push(result[i]);

                                }
                                var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                                return [array.indexOf(string) == -1];
                            },
                            changeYear: false,
                            showWeek: true,
                            firstDay: 1,
                            yearRange: "c-100:c+15",
                            showOn: inp.hasClass("ui-date-picker-onfocus") ? "focus" : "button"

                        })
```

Comment: Has somebody a suggestion? Thank you

Comment: So how to get the date values(that you only can select the availeble dates from the json ) in the datepicker